# Start and stop process from inside procedure in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, process, procedure, multitasking

I want to **create process** controlled by two function one called **Start** which will start the process and update a new value , an other called **Stop** which will Stop the process .

**Note** : the user can start and stop the process multiples times .